# How to block redirect search in robots in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, web-crawler, robots.txt, googlebot

In my wordpress site I've redirected my search from

```
domain.com/?s=search_term
```

to

```
domain.com/search/search_term
```

**In robots.text should I change ?**

```
Disallow: /*?
```

to

```
Disallow: /search/
```

**How can I test that is working properly ?**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disallow search then, yes, you should have the line:

```
Disallow: /search/
```

Google's Webmaster tools has a robots.txt checker. You can use that to test your robots.txt file for validity.